# Mule Application getting redeployed in a loop

Tags: mule

I have a couple of Mule applications running on mule container version 3.3.0. Recently I have observed that one of my mule application is getting redeployed again and again in a loop continuously. 
The Mule app first get deployed then immediately within 2-3 seconds the mule app gets un-deployed and then gets deployed automatically. This is happening in loop and I don't see any specific errors in the log.
Can somebody please help me out with this problem and let me know the reason for the above behavior and how to fix it.

Thanks
Jai

Answer (score 0):

There has to be an error, the problem is probably that you don't see it. Try locating the logfile named mule.log (or mule_ee.log) rather than mule-app-APPNAME.log. You might find the error there.

Otherwise, triple check that there are no weird permissions on the directory app (as the lock file should be created there).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am checking the mule.log and I could only see GC related statements. Full GC is also coming in often. Is the problem I am facing is because of running on out of PermGen due to too many hot deployments?

Comment: You might be suffering a PermGen leak. What libraries are you using? Do your custom classes (if any) attach to the Mule lifecycle somehow? Libraries in lib/user?

Comment: So will the Mule app re-deploy by itself again and again in a loop fashion if there is a PermGen leak or if the PermGen is completely occupied?

Comment: When an app fails, the reason doesnt matter,the app will be redeployed.

Comment: I also get to see lot of "request to undeploy application" messages in mule.log for one of the ESB app which is causing trouble. Why do we get this  "request to undeploy application" messages in mule.log??